# Use an excel template and update it programatically

Tags: asp.net, xml, excel-2007, openxml, excelpackage

I found [this tool](http://excelpackage.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Using%20a%20template%20to%20create%20an%20Excel%20spreadsheet&referringTitle=Home) but I wonder if it still the right way nowdays with net 4.0 or is there any straight forward oob alternatives.

I just need to add columns and update excel stuff programatically. There are many ways but I need to keep the original document as a template. The link above explains exactly what the requeriments are and why they created such "ExcelPackage" library.

Answer (score 0):

A quick look at the link you provided seems like it will in fact keep the original template intact and just return a populated version of that template.  This is a pretty common way to create and populate Excel documents using Open XML since it helps to minimize the amount of code you have to write.  If you did not specify the layout, styles, formats, etc in a template you would be forced to define those when coding and that could lead to some bloated code.  Overall, a project like this or using the [Open XML SDK 2.0](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=c6e744e5-36e9-45f5-8d8c-331df206e0d0&displaylang=en) to create the documents is the way to go.

Comment: you are completely right! Trying to craft the excel into html to be xls exportable can be a nightmare. Doing the other way around is the way to go. I also found some other tools (gembox, I think) that can translate open xml documents (office) to html